# Search for an email in an nvarchar column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, text-parsing

I am looking to search for a particular email (e.g., fname@exmaple.com) in an nvarchar column in SQL Server. It should have been as easy as -

```
Select * from Discussion where Comments like '%fname@example.com%'
```

However the above query is not covering one case. If the result set contains a Comment like "Comment from a user with email selfname@example.com". In this case the above query will return both records containing 'fname@example.com' and 'selfname@example.com'.

I am looking for a sql query where the email address is matched exactly and the rest of text can be anything.

I am trying to search for an email in multiple tables. The column where we are searching for an email could be an xml, nvarchar(max) for comments and nvarchar(50) for just an email. We need to do perform another job on the record set.

Result set:
If I am searching for 'fname@example.com', the result set should contain the below:

1. lorem ipsum fname@exmaple.com
2. fname@example.com lorem ipsum
3. Lorem ipsum fname@exmaple.com dolor sit amet

The result set should not contain something like:

1. selfname@example.com dolor sit amet
2. Lorem ipsum selfname@exmaple.com dolor sit amet

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just add spaces to the mail address? `like '% fname@example.com %'`

Comment: can you please elaborate on what you exactly need in a result ?

Comment: Is the above free type, or will it always be in the format `'Comment from a user with email {Email Address}'`, or could you have something like `'User with email address {Email Address} made a comment'"? Is there text after the email address? Ideally, however, seems like email should be a different column and you should be fixing your design.

Comment: By the way, if you are checking an nvarchar, its good form to then compare to an nvarchar too: `N'%fname@example.com%'`

Comment: I have added some more explanation so as to help understand the problem better.

Comment: Still, you didn't mention what output you are looking for in the above query? like fname@example.com,
fname@example1.com like that?

Comment: @Dhrumilshah -  I have added some examples of what the result set should look like. Thanks.

Comment: Please check my Answer, I tried from my side and tested , it's working from my end

Comment: hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/65424138/9724371

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the below query.

```
declare @searchText nvarchar(50) = 'fname@example.com'

select * 
from Discussion 
where
    Comments = @searchText
    or (
        CHARINDEX(@searchText, Comments) > 0
        and SUBSTRING(Comments, CHARINDEX(@searchText, Comments) - 1, 1) in (' ', '<', '>', '"', '''', ',', ';', '=', '(', ')', '*') 
        and SUBSTRING(Comments, CHARINDEX(@searchText, Comments) + LEN(@searchText), 1) in (' ', '<', '>', '"', '''', ',', ';', '=', '(', ')', '*'))
```

I am looking for either an exact match or otherwise checking the previous and next characters to assess if the match is meeting the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it could be useful to check for a non-alphanumeric character after or before the email (as described here: [LIKE Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15))  and distinguish all possible cases:

1. Email is in the middle
2. Email is at beginning
3. Email is at the end
4. Column only contains the email

   ```
   SELECT * 
     FROM Discussion 
    WHERE Comments LIKE '%[^a-z0-9]fname@example.com[^a-z0-9]%' --CASE 1
       OR Comments LIKE 'fname@example.com[^a-z0-9]%'           --CASE 2
       OR Comments LIKE '%[^a-z0-9]fname@example.com'           --CASE 3
       OR Comments = 'fname@example.com'                        --CASE 4
   ```

In addittion, in this way you can cover cases like "Lorem ipsum:fname@exmaple.com" that you probably would like to detect and it should work ad you described.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we need to find the email address contains in the text, so for that, we need to identify '@' so for that, we need to write a query like below

```
    SELECT Id,Comments as Text,        
                CASE
                    WHEN CHARINDEX('@',Comments) = 0 THEN NULL
                    ELSE SUBSTRING(Comments,beginningOfEmail,endOfEmail-beginningOfEmail)
                END email
         INTO #Temp1 FROM Discussion 
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(' ',Comments + ' ',CHARINDEX('@',Comments ))) AS A(endOfEmail)
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATALENGTH(Comments )/2 - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(' ' + Comments),CHARINDEX('@',REVERSE(' ' + Comments ))) + 2) AS B(beginningOfEmail)
 -- stored data in Temp table , you can use alternative 

SELECT id,email  FROM #Temp1 
DROP table #Temp1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
id  email
1   fname@exmaple.com
2   fname@example.com
3   hname@example.com
4   fname@exmaple.com
5   fname@example1.com
6   selfname@example.com
```

Then we need to do one more filter in the **#Temp** table
like

```
SELECT id,email  FROM #Temp1 
where LEFT(email, CHARINDEX('@', email + '@') -1) like 'fname'
```

**OR**

```
SELECT id,email  FROM #Temp1 
    where LEFT(email, CHARINDEX('@', email + '@') -1) = 'fname'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
id  email
1   fname@exmaple.com
2   fname@example.com
4   fname@exmaple.com
5   fname@example1.com
```

You can copy and paste this query and check its working from my end,

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that the email is at the beginning, end, or surrounded by spaces, then you can use pad the pattern and the `comments` with spaces:

```
where concat(' ', Comments, ' ') like '% fname@example.com %'
```

If there can be other separators -- such as parentheses, syntax, and so on -- then this is tricker.  One method is to replace these with spaces using `translate()`:

```
where concat(' ', translate(Comments, '(),:;', '     '), ' ') like '% fname@example.com %'
```

Unfortunately, `.` is part of the pattern you are looking for, so it is tricky to include that as well.